# How to create a timetable using charts

Tags: c#

For context I'm trying to create something similar to Windows Parental Control

This is what I'm trying to do right now.

- Define X-Axis from 0:00 to 23:59
- Define Y-Axis from 1-7 (Mon. - Sun.)
- Add Point for X1=StartTime X2=EndTime on Y-Axis which is given in comboWeekdays
- X-Axis mustn't adjust (always start from 0:00, even if there are no points there)
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwLYr.jpg like this <

So far I managed to get this https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gFUi.png

```
TimeSpan span = dateEndTime.Value.Subtract(dateStartTime.Value);
        timeInMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(span.TotalMinutes);
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(timeInMinutes));

        if(comboWeekdays.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        selectedWeekday = comboWeekdays.SelectedItem.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(selectedWeekday);

        System.Threading.Timer newTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(LogOff, null, (timeInMinutes * 60000), (timeInMinutes * 60000));

        chartTimeTable.Series.Clear();
        chartTimeTable.Series.Add("Monday");
        chartTimeTable.Series.Add("Tuesday");
        chartTimeTable.Series.Add("Wednesday");
        chartTimeTable.Series.Add("Thursday");
        chartTimeTable.Series.Add("Friday");
        chartTimeTable.Series.Add("Saturday");
        chartTimeTable.Series.Add("Sunday");
```

Comment: Download MSDN samples.  Lots of good examples : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Forms-Samples-26bf2a53

Comment: There are various ways to do this with a Chart. Imo they are all rather hackish. Using a DataGridview will give the the look with much less hassle..